# cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create() is not working

Tags: python, computer-vision, opencv3.0

i am using `cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()` in my google colab but it shows the error:

> OpenCV(3.4.5) /io/opencv_contrib/modules/xfeatures2d/src/sift.cpp:1207: error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented) This algorithm is patented and is excluded in this configuration; Set OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE CMake option and rebuild the library in function 'create'.

i installed contribution using !pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.5.20 but still not working.

```
!pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.5.20

img_1= cv2.imread('pic1.JPG') 
img_2=cv2.imread("pic2.JPG")
img_1=cv2.cvtColor(img_1,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
img_2=cv2.cvtColor(img_2,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
# find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img_1,None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img_2,None)
```

Answer (score -1):

SIFT is not available in Opencv versions > 3.4.2, so you need to downgrade:

```
!pip uninstall opencv-python -y
!pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.17 --force-reinstall
```

Comment: SIFT has been available in the pre-built opencv-contrib-python wheels due to patent expiration since versions 4.3.0 and 3.4.10.